# Hibernate Search with Jpa 2 and lucene java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, jpa, lucene, hibernate-search

I am writing an application where i am trying to make an example on hibernate search with Lucene.
In my database, i got an array named A_ROLE witch contains an **ID** field and a **NAME** field. Into this array i have store the data bellow:

1. 1 - Agalloh
2. 2 - Rorry Galaher
3. 3 - Isis Isis

My entity class looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="A_ROLE")
@NamedQuery(name="ARole.findAll", query="SELECT a FROM ARole a")
@Indexed
public class ARole implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
    @DocumentId
@SequenceGenerator(name="A_ROLE_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName="A_ROLE_SEQ")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="A_ROLE_ID_GENERATOR")
@Column(unique=true, nullable=false, precision=38)
    @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
    //@NumericField
private long id;

@Column(length=50)
    @Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
private String name;

//bi-directional many-to-many association to APermission
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
    name="A_ROLE_PERMISSION"
    , joinColumns={
        @JoinColumn(name="ROLE_ID", nullable=false)
        }
    , inverseJoinColumns={
        @JoinColumn(name="PERMISSION_ID", nullable=false)
        }
    )
private List<APermission> APermissions;

//bi-directional many-to-many association to AUser
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="ARoles")
private List<AUser> AUsers;

    constructor, getters and setters
```

and i have create an interface named DataBaseExchanges which contains a method lucinExample(). This method is responsible for the hibernate search and its implementation is being from the class bellow

```
import ec.ep.europarl.appdif.db.entity.ARole;
import ec.ep.europarl.appdif.service.DataBaseExchanges;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import org.hibernate.search.jpa.FullTextEntityManager;
import org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.QueryBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service("dataSearch")
public class DataBaseExchangesImpl implements DataBaseExchanges {

@PersistenceContext
public EntityManager em;

@Override
@Transactional
public void lucinExample() {
    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager =
   org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);
    //em.getTransaction().begin();

    QueryBuilder qb = 
    fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder()
    .forEntity(ARole.class).get();
    org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = qb
            .keyword()
            .onFields("name")
            .matching("agalloh")
            .createQuery();

    // wrap Lucene query in a javax.persistence.Query
    org.hibernate.search.jpa.FullTextQuery persistenceQuery =
    fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(query, ARole.class);

    // execute search
    List result = persistenceQuery.getResultList();

    em.close();
}
```

}

i call this method from a controller, where i have @Autowird the above mentioned interface.

When i debug the above functionality it stops at this line of the implementation code:

```
org.hibernate.search.jpa.FullTextQuery persistenceQuery =
    fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(query, ARole.class);
```

with error report:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appdif] in context with path [] threw exception   
[Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  
org/hibernate/BasicQueryContract] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.BasicQueryContract
at   
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
at
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
at 
org.hibernate.search.impl.FullTextSessionImpl.createFullTextQuery
(FullTextSessionImpl.java:81)
at
org.hibernate.search.jpa.impl.FullTextEntityManagerImpl.
createFullTextQuery(FullTextEntityManagerImpl.java:112)
at
ec.ep.europarl.appdif.service.impl.DataBaseExchangesImpl.
lucinExample(DataBaseExchangesImpl.java:43)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.
invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.
invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy102.lucinExample(Unknown Source)
at ec.ep.europarl.appdif.web.controllers.HomeController.home(HomeController.java:27)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I can't figure out what the problem is, at my maven dependencies i have include hibernate search 4.5.0.Final.
Please can anyone help on this?

Comment: btw, you can remove `@DocumentId from the mapping and probably also the `@Field on the id property (but I don't know your exact usecase). `@Id will sufficiently mark the id property as id used for Hibernate Search.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got answer to my question, i realize that i haven't include this in pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```